# What is the meaning of totalBytesProcessedAccuracy in Jobs.Insert API DryRun response

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed a field called `totalBytesProcessedAccuracy` in the response of [Jobs.Insert API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) when setting the query configuration to DryRun=true.

```
    "query": {
       "totalBytesProcessed": "341880728292",
       "totalBytesBilled": "0",
       "totalBytesProcessedAccuracy": "UPPER_BOUND",
       "cacheHit": false,
       "referencedTables": [
        {
         "projectId": "mydata-1470162410749",
         "datasetId": "EVALUEX_PROD",
         "tableId": "tables"
        }
       ]
```

From my experiment I see 2 values for this field:

1. UPPER_BOUND: when **I use** a query with a cluster field in the `WHERE`
2. PRECISE: When **I'm not using** a query with a cluster field in the `WHERE`

I search BigQuery documentation for this field to get a better explanation on this but couldn't find any reference

Any ideas of how can I find more details about this field and what it means?

Comment: good catch! definitely having this in documentation would be great and hope it will be there soon, but meantime I think those values are pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: just to double check - were you running it under the dry run?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant question updated to reflect your point, Tnk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With traditional tables BigQuery knows exactly how many bytes it will query before the query is ran (dry run):

```
SELECT SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2019` 
WHERE DATE(datehour)='2019-01-05'
AND wiki='en'
AND title='Shakira'

estimated bytes to be processed:  6.36 GB
actual bytes processed:  6.36 GB
```

But with clustered tables it's hard to know how many bytes will be actually processed. So the best BigQuery can do for now is tell you the maximum bytes that could be processed:

```
SELECT SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
WHERE DATE(datehour)='2019-01-05'
AND wiki='en'
AND title='Shakira'

estimated bytes to be processed:  6.36 GB (upper bound)
actual bytes processed:  148 MB
```

By switching from my `v2` tables to `v3` (the ones I have clustered), this query is saving 98% of data processed costs. On the other hand, you have to accept that a dry run can only give you an "upper bound" of what it will cost.

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

Comment: thank you, Is there a plan to change accuracy level after the cluster feature will from Beta to full release?

Comment: to create or track feature requests please use https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654